# Python calling class methods from external module

Tags: python, class, module, function-calls

I need help please, I have searching but none of the answers I found is working for my problem

I need to set a variable in a class method in another module

(frist.py)

```
class car(object)
   @staticmethod
   def reg_number(self, regno):
       self.builder.get_object("label1").set_text(regno)

   def __init__(self):
       self.data = Data()

.
.
.
.
if __name__ == "__main__":
     app = car()
     gtk.main()
```

(second.py)

```
from first import car

def set_reg_no():
    cr = car()
    cr.reg_number('CVM107')
```

The call to cr.reg_number('CVM107') is raising an error.
I have tried car.reg_number('CVM107'), first.car.reg_number('CVM107') among a lot of other combinations but I keep getting errors

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Piet

Comment: Post the full traceback in the question body.

Comment: There is no `self` in a staticmethod. Please remove the the `@staticmethod` if you expect to get an instance passed.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the self argument in the staticmethod:
Like this:

```
>>> class car(object):
...     @staticmethod
...     def test(str):
...             print str
... 
>>> car.test('a')
a
```